# Running computation using multiple sub-selects in SQL

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there a way to write this SQL query in SQL?

```
select (select count(*) from a) / (select count(*) from b) as ratio;
```

I've done the obvious:

```
DB.fetch("select (select count(*) from a) / (select count(*) from b) as ratio")
```

but I'm wondering whether there is a more idiomatic SQL way of doing this.

Comment: I appreciate the answers so far, but just to clarify, I'm interested in whether there's a way to write this in idiomatic Ruby using Sequel, the Ruby ORM framework, as distinct from SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Sequel::Dataset is not able to use all of the methods that other Sequel::Expression subclasses can use, though it probably should be able to handle at least some of them.  You can use the sql_expr extension that ships with Sequel to handle this:

```
Sequel.extension :sql_expr
DB.select((DB[:a].select{count(:*){}}.sql_expr /
  DB[:b].select{count(:*){}}).as(:ratio))
# SELECT ((SELECT count(*) FROM a) /
#   (SELECT count(*) FROM b)) AS ratio
```

Comment: Who better to know the answer to this than Jeremy Evans himself? Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @A int = (select count(*) from a);
Declare @B int = (select count(*) from b);

select convert(decimal(15,3), @A) / convert(decimal(15,3), @B) as Ratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could me more idiomatic than that. You query seems perfectly fine. Whatever the replacement could be, it would be more verbous at the very least and not necessarily clearer. (I mean, it could be just as clear and idiomatic as your query).

But if you insist, here's a possible variation:

```
SELECT a.cnt / b.cnt AS ratio
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a) a (cnt),
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b) b (cnt)
```

There could be one issue, though. You are dividing an integer by an integer. Some database servers perform integer division in such cases, which might bring you an unexpected result. For example, `90 / 100` would yield `0`, while `2000 / 1001` would result in `1`.

To address the issue, you need to perform the division on non-integer numerics. It is enough to convert just one of the operands to a non-integer numeric type for the result to be more sensible. You can use an explicit conversion, like [@hamlin11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195168/running-computation-using-multiple-sub-selects-in-sql/6195943#6195943) has demonstrated, or you could convert implicitly like this:

```
SELECT a.cnt * 1.0 / b.cnt AS ratio
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a) a (cnt),
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b) b (cnt)
```

Or, applying directly to your script:

```
select (select count(*) from a) * 1.0 / (select count(*) from b) as ratio;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about integer division -- that's definitely a valid point. MySQL, which is what I'm using, does return a float, but as you point out that's not guaranteed on other DB servers.